# Python 3 error 403 when downloading file

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, python-3.4

I'm using a script to grab download links from an HTML page (sent to me via mail) and then download the files, the script has been working great for about 6 months, but last week i started getting "403 Error".

from what I've read and understand, the issue is that the site is blocking me, thinking that it's a bot (can't deny that), but I'm not scraping the HTML code of the site, just trying to download a file using `requests.get`, I only get this error from one specific site, other ones I can download fine.

I've tried setting `headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}` but that didn't help.

here's the function that downloads the file:

```
def download_file(dl_url, local_save_path):
        """Download URL to given path"""
        user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.101 Safari/537.36'

        auth_check = requests.get(dl_url, auth=(username.get(), password.get()), verify=False, headers={'User-Agent': user_agent})

        dnl_sum = 1024
        local_filename = dl_url.split('/')[-1]
        complete_name = os.path.join(local_save_path, local_filename)

        # Get file size
        r = requests.head(dl_url, auth=(username.get(), password.get()), verify=False, headers={'User-Agent': user_agent})
        try:
            dl_file_size = int(r.headers['content-length'])
            file_size.set(str(int(int(r.headers['content-length']) * (10 ** -6))) + "MB")
            c = 1
        except KeyError:
            c = 0
            pass
        # NOTE the stream=True parameter
        print('1')
        r = requests.get(dl_url, stream=True, auth=(username.get(), password.get()), verify=False, headers={'User-Agent': user_agent})
        print('2')
        while True:
            try:
                with open(complete_name, 'wb') as f:
                    for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
                        if chunk:  # filter out keep-alive new chunks
                            f.write(chunk)
                            f.flush()
                            if c == 1:
                                download_perc.set(percentage(dl_file_size, dnl_sum))
                            elif c == 0:
                                print(dnl_sum)
                            dnl_sum = os.path.getsize(complete_name)
            except FileNotFoundError:
                continue
            break
    return
```

Comment: Ok, so you already know that you've been blocked. What exactly do you expect from us? We don't have power to unblock you. And you should realize that any other action might be illegal.

Comment: I would suspect it is IP-based block, so maybe look up some proxy services...

Comment: I second freakish. In addition your user_agent looks quiet broken.

Comment: If I download the files manually (ie click the link in the mail or enter the URL in the browser) I don't get any errors so i don't think I'm blocked, also this is an internal site for our company so I'm not worried about anything illegal.

Comment: @AlexZel Then ask in your company why they suddenly started responding with 403. And that they should unblock you (yes, you are blocked, that's exactly what 403 means). It will be much faster, easier and reliable then proxying requests.

Comment: Believe me if I knew who to talk to about this I would, but the site is managed half way around the world and no contact information is given. Is my username blocked or my IP? Will running the scrip on another PC maybe resolve this?

Comment: @AlexZel Dude, if you can't reach anyone responsible for this kind of things then leave that company. :) Anyway you can try changing username or IP (i.e. changing machine should be fine). But still it is not how you solve this kind of problems. You don't hack your own employer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to use a proxy ?
You can use tor, it's allow you dynamic IP address and website can't recognize you.

Try this https://techoverflow.net/blog/2015/02/06/using-python-requests-over-tor/